# How to escape URL-parameter to prevent HTML injection

Tags: php, html, code-injection

What is a good way to escape the URL-parameter in the last line of the code to prevent HTML injection through the parametrized href url? I mean in the:
editform.php?id=' . **$row["CustomerID"]** . '">' part.

```
require_once 'common.php';

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY CustomerID DESC");
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($results && $stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
{ 

echo '<h2>Results</h2>';

//Here comes some plain HTML for table design.

//Then a FOR loop.
foreach ($results as $row) 
{ 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="editform.php?id=' . $row["CustomerID"] . '">' . $row["CustomerID"] . '</a></td>';
```

I was thinking to write a function in the common.php. Something like:

```
function escape($html)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");
}
```

Will that be conclusive? Or should I use something like:
filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

Comment: Use just `htmlspecialchars ($row["CustomerID"])`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: There's no need to escape it there, because users can just unescape it in the address bar. Escape `$_GET['id']` on the `editform.php` page before you use its value.

Comment: OK, that make sense to me, however I thought that it was good practice to validate your data that comes in, and only escape or encode when you are sending it as output or use it in another string.

Comment: @Bret Yes, that's generally true for values you do not control. IDs are things you should have control over. But you *should* escape the user's name before displaying it if the user was able to enter it themselves and you're not sure you sanitised it properly before you saved it. `htmlspecialchars()` is a good way to do that for HTML output. If you want to use their name in the URL, use `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for link and [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for text.

```
echo '<td><a href="editform.php?id=' .  urlencode($row["CustomerID"]) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row["CustomerID"], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8") . '</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

For any component of an URL, you need to URL-encode it (using `urlencode`). This will avoid issues in the URL itself with spaces, special characters, and `&`.

Then you need to escape the full attribute value with `htmlspecialchars`. The same applies to any text you include in your HTML.

Comment: I want to thank everybody for the quick answers and suggestions. This will keep me covered for the moment. I will keep an eye on the topic for other suggestions. Thanks.